# Append a line as a new line after printing columns horizontaly

Tags: awk, printf

I have a tab-separated file named infile like this.

```
Date    01-01-2022 
Type    Inventory
Number  120
Log     202022
Lot     300
```

I want to print the second column horizontally. The code and output are as follows.

```
awk -F'\t' '{printf "%14s", $2}' infile ; printf '\n%s\n'
 01-01-2022      Inventory           120        202022           300
```

I want to print the output to a file as `>> outfile` since each day a new line is expected to add to outfile since inventory information may change. How can I print the output to a file using `>> outfile` in the above code? If I add `>> outfile` at the end of the above code, the output prints to the screen. The expected output, if I run the same code twice on the same day is as follows.

```
 01-01-2022      Inventory           120        202022           300
 01-01-2022      Inventory           120        202022           300
```

Is there a better way to do this? Help me please I am a newbie in awk. Thanks.

Comment: You're passing the file to `awk` to read line-by-line, how is it supposed to know where to start if you aren't telling it? Alternatively, just don't append.

Comment: @miken32 - Start from the first row of infile. (I removed the file name from the file content). How to add a new row each day to outfile assuming the code is run every day? This is to keep track of records each day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

Wrap the current code in braces and direct the output to your file, eg:

```
{ awk -F'\t' '{printf "%14s", $2}' infile ; printf '\n%s\n' ; } >> outfile
```

Another option would be to have `awk` add the `\n`, eg:

```
awk -F'\t' '{printf "%14s", $2} END {print ""}' infile >> outfile
```

Where the `END{}` block is called after all input lines have been processed and the `print ""` just prints a blank/empty string *plus* a `\n`.